# dynamic programming solution for a string ending with 0, 1 or 2

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

A string that contains only `0s`, `1s`, and `2s` is called a ternary string. Find a total ternary strings of length `n` that do not contain two consecutive `0s` or two consecutive `1s`.

I have defined a recurrence relation as `dp[i][j]` means the total number os trings ending with `j` where `i` is the length of the string and `j` is either `0`, `1` or `2`.

dp[i][0] = dp[i-1][1] + dp[i-1][2]

dp[i][1] = dp[i-1][0] + dp[i-1][2]

dp[i][2] = dp[i-1][1] + dp[i-1][2] + dp[i-1][1]

```
from collections import defaultdict

def end_with_x(n):
  dp = defaultdict(int)
  dp[1] = defaultdict(int)
  dp[1][0] = 1
  dp[1][1] = 1
  dp[1][2] = 1
  for i in range(2, n+1):
    dp[i] = defaultdict(int)
    dp[i][0] = dp[i-1][1] + dp[i-1][2]
    dp[i][1] = dp[i-1][0] + dp[i-1][2]
    dp[i][2] = dp[i-1][2] + dp[i-1][0] + dp[i-1][1]
  return dp[n][0] + dp[n][1] + dp[n][2]
print(end_with_x(2))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your recurrence is very fine, so I've just minor adjustments to propose:

- In this kind of bottom-up DP, you only need to access the previous row. No need to keep the whole history.
- There is a copy/paste bug in `dp[i][0]` computation.
- No need to use a `dict`, each level (row) is fully filled out.

I would thus write:

```
def total_with_length(n):
    if n <= 0:
        return 0
    n0, n1, n2 = 1, 1, 1
    for _ in range(n-1):
        n0, n1, n2 = n1+n2, n0+n2, n0+n1+n2
    return n0 + n1 + n2
```

Comment: Can I suggest writing that line as: 
`n0, n1, n2 = (n1 + n2), (n0 + n2), (n0 + n1 + n2)`

Comment: @foxyblue You can!